# write to the file system in a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to write to the file system in a directory C: \ directory name, for the moment I have this code:

```
if (! System.IO.File.Exists (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath (filename)))
{
   TXTFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath (filename));
}
else
{
   TXTFile = System.IO.File.AppendText (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath (filename));
}
```

but in this way writes on the application folder.
How to fix it?

Comment: you don't need to use mappath if you already have a c:\ like path. Mappath is used when you have a server path and need to have a c:\ like path...

Comment: Also, since this appears to be an ASP.NET application, you may not have access to the path you're trying to write to.

Answer (score 5):

Just do

```
Path.Combine(@"C:\", filename)
```

instead of

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath (filename)
```

Ensure your application has write access to the destination.

Comment: You mean `"C:\\"` or `@"C:\"` me thinks

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are doing this from a web application?

Although it is possible (with the correct rights) to write to the C:\ root, it is not very good practice.

You'd probably be safer to save it somewhere else. Also look into this method [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)